# Find differences in record sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-outer-join

I want to know if 2 record sets are different. I use a `full outer join` for that. Simple example:

```
select count(*) from 
(
 select 1 as c
 union 
 select 2 as c 
) t1
full outer join 
(
 select 1 as c 
 union 
 select 3 as c
) t2 on t1.c = t2.c
where t1.c is null or t2.c is null
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/24930)

If the record sets are equal then the `count()` returns `0`.

Is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: May we assume that `c` is a unique column in each record set?

Comment: Yes, it is just like that

Comment: [***Outer Results LINK***](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/nonmatchingrows/) I think these are your two best options; 1) the way you have written -or- 2) `EXCEPT` method

Answer (score 1):

If `c` in your record sets are unique, you can do it using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT c FROM (
        SELECT c FROM record_set_1
    UNION ALL
        SELECT c FROM record_set_2
    ) all_data
    GROUP BY c
    HAVING COUNT(*) <> 2
) non_matched
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/24935)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `EXISTS`:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT null FROM t1 where c NOT IN (SELECT c FROM t2))
OR EXISTS(SELECT null FROM t2 where c NOT IN (SELECT c FROM t1))
```

Of course that doesn't tell you *which* records do not match - if you want to know that your original query is just fine.